# Understanding SameQ

Tags: expression-test

I am new to Mathematica. So I have read the documentation for comparing expressions in Mathematica and I still don't get the SameQ (===) function. Let me give you a short example:

```
2+2 === 4
True

Log[x*x] === 2*Log[x]
False
```

I hope I'm not seeing something here. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

Every expression in Mathematica is characterized by it's FullForm.

So in your case particularly

`FullForm[Log[x*x]]===Log[Power[x,2]]`

and

`FullForm[2*Log[x]]===Times[2,Log[x]]`

These two, although equivalent from a Mathematical point of view (but only if x>0) they have different FullForm representations.

So SameQ(===) checks if the expression trees are the same.

In case more conditions are induced (like x>0) and simplifications take place then you will certainly end up to same expressions.

`Assuming[x > 0, Simplify[Log[x*x]]]===2*Log[x]`

returns `True`

Comment: +1 Note that for approximate numbers, there can be difference between numbers that are considered the same. Compare `1. + $MachineEpsilon === 1.` and `FullForm /@ {1. + $MachineEpsilon, 1.}`.  The tolerance is controlled by ``Internal`$SameQTolerance``.  Also, as you almost point out, for `x == -1`, the identity fails: `{Log[(-1)^2], 2 Log[-1]}` equals `{0, 2 I Pi}`.

Comment: True about the approximate numbers! I think it is better to avoid those when checking with `SameQ`. True also about the complex solutions - We could also say that x is an object different than the usual where also the identity holds but this would be going to far :-)

Comment: But what is the problem in this case:
    1/(a)^(3/4) === (1/a)^(3/4)
returns False

Comment: @drabus `1/(a)^(3/4) === Simplify[(1/a)^(3/4), a > 0]`