# Can Mathematica point out why it thinks two symbolic expressions are different?

Tags: expression-test

`SameQ` checks to see if symbolic expressions are the same. There are some caveats, as pointed out by the answers to:

- [Understanding SameQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72516/understanding-sameq)
- [What is the proper way to verify that two expressions are equivalent?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38851/what-is-the-proper-way-to-verify-that-two-expressions-are-equivalent)

Consider the following two expressions:

```
s = ((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) Abs[ay bx-ax by-ay px+by px+ax py-bx py] > 0 ||
    ((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) ((ax-bx) (bx-px)+(ay-by) (by-py)) > 0 ||
    ((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) (ax^2+ay^2+bx px-ax (bx+px)+by py-ay (by+py)) < 0

t = ((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) Abs[ay bx-ax by-ay px+by px+ax py-bx py] > 0 ||
    ((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) (ax^2+ay^2+bx px-ax (bx+px)+by py-ay (by+py)) < 0 ||
    ((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) ((ax-bx) (bx-px)+(ay-by) (by-py)) > 0
```

On Mathematica 9:

```
In[47]:= s == t
Out[47]= (((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) Abs[ay bx-ax by-ay px+by px+ax py-bx py] > 0 ||
((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) ((ax-bx) (bx-px)+(ay-by) (by-py)) > 0 || 
((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) (ax^2+ay^2+bx px-ax (bx+px)+by py-ay (by+py)) < 0) == 
(((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) Abs[ay bx-ax by-ay px+by px+ax py-bx py] > 0 || 
((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) (ax^2+ay^2+bx px-ax (bx+px)+by py-ay (by+py)) < 0 ||
((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2) ((ax-bx) (bx-px)+(ay-by) (by-py)) > 0)

In[48]:= s === t
Out[48]= False

In[49]:= Assuming[{ax, bx, px, ay, by, py} \[Element] Reals, s === t]
Out[49]= False

In[50]:= Assuming[{ax, bx, px, ay, by, py} \[Element] Reals, FullSimplify[s === t]]
Out[50]= False
```

Can I get Mathematica to identify where it thinks the statements are different?

Comment: It's the ordering,of course-. Try `Sort[t] == Sort[s]`

Comment: @belisarius `Sort::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Sort[t]`

Comment: Well, it works here. Please restart your Mathematica and try again. Just in case, I'm also using v9

Comment: Are you sure you want `SameQ` and not `Equal`?  `SameQ` tests for structural equality of two data structures, and has nothing to do with mathematics.  `Assuming`, `Simplify`, etc. have absolutely no effect on it because those functions are for symbolic mathematics.  `SameQ` is purely for programming.  If two things don't look *exactly* the same according to `FullForm`, then they are different for `SameQ`.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry it's kind of a mess (I'm a little bit sleep-deprived at the moment), but here's something that might work for you:

```
Module[{cf = ColorData[97], $color = 1},
style["", c_] := Style[Overscript[Overscript["", \[OverBracket]], c], {Darker@cf[c], Bold}];
style[str_, c_] := Style[Overscript[Overscript[str, \[OverBracket]], c], {Darker@cf[c], Bold}];
join[{Row[{}], Row[{}]}, next_String] := ($color = 1;{Row[{next}], Row[{next}]});
    join[{Row[{}], Row[{}]}, {next1_String, next2_String}] := ($color = 1;{Row[{next1}], Row[{next2}]});
join[{s1_Row, s2_Row}, next_String] := {Row[{s1, next}], Row[{s2, next}]};
join[{s1_Row, s2_Row}, {next1_String, next2_String}] := With[{c = $color++}, {Row[{s1, style[next1, c]}], Row[{s2, style[next2, c]}]}];
    highlightDifference[s_, t_] := Column[Fold[join, {Row[{}], Row[{}]}, SequenceAlignment[ToString[s, InputForm], ToString[t, InputForm]]]];
]
```

[image]